# How to check if term exists?

Tags: prolog

```
user(admin).
user(guest).
```

How to check if admin exists? Otherwise:

```
assert(user(admin)).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, predicates like `user/1` that can be dynamically added to the database are declared as such:

```
:- dynamic(user/1).
```

You can query whether user admin exists:

```
?- user(admin).
false.
```

Now, if you add user admin, the same query succeeds:

```
?- assert(user(admin)).
true.
?- user(admin).
true.
```

It is possible to come up with a predicate that does this automatically, without a dynamic declaration in place:

```
add_to_db(Fact):-
   current_predicate(_, Fact),
   Fact, !.
add_to_db(Fact):-
  assertz(Fact).
```

Comment: it's not what i'm interested about. How can I check if `user(admin)` added to db?

Comment: @user3360601 If `?- user(admin)` returns `true` then you know that it was added to the database. If it return `false`you know this it was not added to the database.

Comment: I have replaced the rather crude use of exception catching with the less 'hacky' approach of using `current_predicate/2`. (Thanks to someone's comment to this post that now seems to be gone?)